# Changing the values of constant parameters in a program when we call this program in the other program

Tags: c++

I have a c++ program. In the beginning of this program I have defined some parameters like this and I am using these parameters in my code, lets call it: "first.cpp";

```
#define column  6    //number of columns in the mat1
#define row  5     //number of rows in the mat1 
int main(){
...
}
```

Now I want to execute this "first.cpp" program in another program named "second.cpp".
Does anyone knows how can I call first.cpp in second.cpp and what should I do for the initialization of those 2 above parameters (column & row) in the second.cpp ? 
Actually, I want to run a c++ program(first.cpp) in another program(second.cpp) for several times and in each time I want to change the values of (column & row), how it could be possible? ...
in fact, I have:

```
#define column  6    
#define row  5   
int func1(int a[][column],int b[][row]);  
int main(){
...
}
```

As you see I am defining a 2d array as an argument in func1 and according to the c rules it is necessary that I use some value for the second dimension. That is why I am defining these parameters before main()... and because of some limitation I don't like to define 2d array with pointers...that was the reason...

Comment: You could write the program you want to call such that it takes in command line arguments for row and column and then assign those two arguments to two variables for row and column.

Comment: You may visit this site: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/167249-how-do-i-call-in-one-c-file-into-another/

Comment: How can I write my parameters as the main argument while I am defining them before main?!and because of some reasons, it is necessary that I use them before main

Comment: @shirin _"it is necessary that I use them before main"_ You're lost then, there's no way. Consider dynamic storage allocations instead of global static stuff.

Comment: You wouldn't be using `#define` with what I suggested. You would instead have them be variables defined right at the beginning of main. If you need to use them before main you can declare them as globals but there is no way of doing it the way I suggested without first defining them in main.

Comment: @NickLamp I'd suspect the OP asks for some hard coded global c-style arrays.

Comment: @shirin As a good advice, use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays. This would save yourself from a lot of headaches.

Comment: good suggestion, thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how it could be possible?

It's not possible as long you're sticking to your `#define` preprocessor constants. These are fixed into your `first.cpp` after you compiled it.

What you can do instead (as mentioned in [@NickLamp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4544684/nicklamp)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35730263/changing-the-values-of-constant-parameters-in-a-program-when-we-call-this-progra#comment59135477_35730263)): Provide these constants as command line parameters.

You may consider to set these to default values, if no command line parameters are given.

Answer (score 1):

You can make first.cpp into a library(static library is a good choise),  and call it from your second.cpp program, and you should not use  `"int func1(int a[][column],int b[][row]);"`  signature, instead it could be  `"int func1(int a[][],int b[][], column, row)"` , and remove the "#define"s. The remaining work is to implement this function.